# Twilio webhook - 403, invalid signature - node/express

Tags: javascript, twilio, webhooks

**EDIT: I have fixed it, twilio has different 'regions', and each region has its own Auth token, my webhooks were set up in Ireland, but I was using the auth token for US. Changing to the correct region auth token fixed it.**

I've been trying to validate a twilio webhook & spent nearly a full day trying to make this work. I've tested in both ngrok + my digital ocean app platform with the correct webhook url/twilio auth and no matter what i'm getting a 403 Forbidden

I also have no logs at all in the Error Logs, the last ones were from 6 hours ago and nothing regarding the failed authentications

I've also tried the webhook() and get the same result,

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong? I was trying to hesitate to post this, but i'm at my wits end with it.

The webhook is for call tracking, the endpoint itself is complete in everything but the validation, i'm creating a table row based off the incoming call

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const twilioAuthToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
  const twilioWebhookUrl = process.env.TWILIO_WEBHOOK_URL;

  // Validate the request
  if (twilio.validateRequest(twilioAuthToken, req.headers['x-twilio-signature'], twilioWebhookUrl, req.body)) {

  } else {
    console.log('Invalid Twilio Signature');
    return res.status(403).send('Invalid Twilio Signature');
  }

}
```

- Tried in both production and locally
- Tried multiple auth tokens

Comment: Great that you were able to fix it. Would you mind copying the solution down to the "answers" section? This way, you can mark the question as answered.